# Estimating OpenCL memory access performance for algorithm design

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have a task which I need to achieve using one of several possible algorithm.

Each algorithm, has its own opportunities for local-memory optimization, and I would like to estimate which algorithm will perform best, based on counting compute operations and memory access.

For the purpose of comparing different number of local memory access operations vs. global memory access operations, I would like to estimate the price (in cycles?) of local memory access (read / write) vs the price of global memory access.

How many cycles does it take (on a modern, consumer GPU) to perform each of these:

- read from local memory
- write to local memory
- read from global memory
- write to global memory

Note: I use "local memory" and "global memory" in their meaning in OpenCL.

Comment: @Ben-Un, I am not sure I have understood your question 100%, but did you see bandwidth test sample?

Comment: No, what's this? I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: @Ben-Un. What you would measure is local memory bandwidth and global memory bandwidth. I have seen an example that test global memory bandwidth. It is called  [GlobalMemoryBandwidth](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/app-sdk/codelisting.php?q=Accelerated%20Parallel%20Processing).

Comment: But I want to estimate it on the "average" GPU of my users (which I don't know who they are yet). Isn't there a common estimate for these numbers?

Comment: Look at the source code, the method for calculating these things will be the same for all opencl supporting GPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, access to local memory tooks couple of GPU cycles. Access to global memory tooks tens of cycles. From one video card to another numbers differ significantly. So that are very general numbers, which only show difference of magnitude.

As I understand, you're concerned about low-level optimization. If that's right, than you can use software, which is usually shipped with SDK by GPU vendor. Many of them (AMD, ARM, etc) provides offline compilers, which allows export of clProgramm's compiled binaries assembler with instructions-per-cycle information. Then you will get most definite numbers.